# How to search for a specific string occurrence in stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that selects particular `stored procedures`, `triggers` and `functions` in my SQL database. I have retrieved 86 in total.

I need to find which of these are using a certain string inside.
This string is a name of a `table`.

I do not want to open each of these individually and search for it.

I'm thinking of having a script that looks inside of these and find what I need.

What I think I might need is something like `from tableName` or `inner join on tableName` or `join on tableName` and etc

What is a good way to do it in `SQL`

Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL

Comment: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Be very afraid. You don't want to be trying to parse out `from dbo.[Table]`, `from Table1, TableB`, `left outer join [TableIII]`, ... . And not getting tripped up by `select T1Count as [From Table1] ...`. See GarethD's answer. Also see [SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) from Red Gate.

Comment: @HABO Exactly! I was just editing my answer to demonstrate the possible problems with `LIKE '%TableName%'` but now I don't have to! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search one SQL Server database for a specific piece of text in a stored procedure you could do this:

```
DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(100) = 'TableXYZ';
SELECT DISTINCT 
    o.name,
    o.type_desc
FROM 
    sys.sql_modules m 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE 
    m.[definition] Like '%' + @SearchText + '%';
```

Obviously this is a bit of a hack and won't work out if your table name is called something daft like "SELECT" as that will just cause loads of false-positive results.

One alternative is to use the sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities system table, but my experience with this is that it can't be trusted.  In general dependencies don't work very well with SQL Server due to some poor design decisions, e.g. deferred name resolution.

Comment: what if I have stored procedures that uses that string. How will I search inside of existing stored procs?

Comment: Thank you, it might work. What is the difference between sql_modules and sys.objetcs?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL would cover Access, Sybase and SQL Server (and possibly more) .... But I suspect you are using SQL Server, as such I would suggest [sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb630351.aspx) rather than searching a definition for a particular string -

```
SELECT r.* , o.type_desc, m.definition
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('dbo.TableName', 'OBJECT') AS r
    INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS o
        ON o.[object_id] = r.referencing_id
    INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
        ON m.[object_id] = o.[object_id];
```

Comment: ..and here's a quick link to show why these can't always be trusted: https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and easy to use `Sql query`

```
SELECT name
FROM   sys.procedures
WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE '%strHell%'
```

And here's a [link](http://www.zilckh.com/how-to-search-a-text-in-stored-procedure-trigger-function-or-view/) for more info